# Multiple Photos Upload Using ActiveAdmin + CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

I am trying to upload multiple photos using carrierwave and activeadmin gem. But the problem is Rails says there is `Unpermitted parameter: photos`, even though I have added photos to `permit_params` of activeadmin gem.

`#app/admin/apartment_post.rb`

Code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ApartmentPost do
  permit_params :title, :max_stay, :bed_configuration, :number_of_guests, 
                            :rate, :features, :description, photos: []
  form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :max_stay
      f.input :bed_configuration
      f.input :number_of_guests
      f.input :rate
      f.input :features
      f.input :description
      f.input :photos, as: :file, multiple: true
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

`#app/model/apartment_post.rb`

Code:

```
class ApartmentPost < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :photos, PhotoUploader
  validates :title, :max_stay, :bed_configuration, :number_of_guests,
            :rate, :features, :description, presence: true
end
```

`schema.rb`

Code:

```
create_table "apartment_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "max_stay",          null: false
  t.string   "bed_configuration", null: false
  t.integer  "number_of_guests",  null: false
  t.float    "rate",              null: false
  t.string   "features",          null: false
  t.string   "description",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  t.string   "title",             null: false
  t.json     "photos"
end
```

The `photo_uploader.rb` file is default as set by carrierwave.

Any help is highly appriciated, Thank You.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the empty array for `photos`. Instead, `:photos` should be added comparable to the existing `permit_params`.

A great blog post on handling JSON fields: https://lorefnon.me/2015/03/02/dealing-with-json-fields-in-active-admin.html

Comment: But carrierwave requires empty array to upload multiple images

Comment: Documentation says you need to point empty array in a hash. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.

Comment: I am already doing that using `photos: []` on strong params

Comment: @RabinGaire, can you please post here how your params look like?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, found some extra information on the https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1653

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late reply :).

Hope this will help you.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ApartmentPost do
  permit_params :title, :max_stay, :bed_configuration, :number_of_guests, 
                            :rate, :features, :description, { photos: [] }

  form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :max_stay
      f.input :bed_configuration
      f.input :number_of_guests
      f.input :rate
      f.input :features
      f.input :description
      f.file_field :photos, multiple: true
    end
   f.actions
end
```

Are you really able to upload multiple files with as: :file(2nd parameter) in the input method ?.

What I inspect is specifying as: :file in the second parameter is not allowing to input multiple images. It generates below html file tag and you are trying to get photos attribute as an array as the whitelisted parameter.

```
<input id="photos" type="file" name="apartment_post[photos]">
```

There is a ease way rails have provided with file_field. The file_field helper method returns a html input file tag. Try with file_field.
for more details
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field

I am not sure this is causing a error or not in your end but possible reason.

After making the above changes. if you still encounter the problem. you can check the params with debugger by overriding the create action or the function which whitelist the params as below.

```
  controller do
    def create
      aparment_params = params.require(:apartment_post).permit(:title, 
                                                          { photos: [] })
      // here you can use your debugger to check the params.

    end
  end
```

The permitted_params function returns the whitelisted parameter please also check the permitted params.
https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html

And.. If you still face the problem let me know. I will try my best to help you :). Good luck.